# Issue with joomgallery appended to menu item alias

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have a Joomla 3.2.3 site and it has started making very strange alias on menu items. This just started to happen in the last few days, before it was creating the menu item alias/urls as expected.

All of my new menu items have `/com-joomgallery-ajax-upload` added to the beginning of the menu alias.

For example I go into the a menu and make a new menu item of type Single Article, set the title to "Member Login", choose the article I want to use and save. The menu item is under the root of the menu. The link to the page becomes:

`/com-joomgallery-ajax-upload/member-login` rather than just: `/member-login`.

The redirect Manager is not enabled. I don't have any 3rd party SEF extensions installed. I am using the Joomla SEF Friendly URLs with mod_rewrite enabled.

Does anyone have any idea how to 'fix' this problem?

Comment: What URLs are generated with SEF disabled - are they strange themselves? Also, what version of Joomgallery is installed?

Comment: Try using the "Rebuild Menus" link in the menu manager.

Comment: If you're issue is fixed, please post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the hierachical menu-item order gets a bit messy. Due to the complexity of nested sets this can happen if a proccess was interrupted. In most cases a rebuilding of the structure fixes that issue. You will find a corresponding button in your toolbar if you enter the menu manager.